# Hide option which is present in the array object (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

I have select tag like this

```
<select> 
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

i want to **hide** the options which are present in the following array object as a **priority**.

```
$scope.items = [{itemname:abc, priority:2},{itemname:def,priority:4}]
```

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call a method to check for visibility of option via `ng-show or ng-hide`.

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efovt3py/).

further your `itemname` should be string, like `itemname:'abc'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use ng-options:

```
<select ng-options="item for item in items">
```

And "items" - must be array in your controller. So you can manipulate by it

Comment: I think question is about hiding of options if same `priority` is exist in `$scope.items` array.